# Empty body in API Gateway response

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, aws-api-gateway

I have been trying to get the response from API gateway, but after countless tries and going through several online answers, I still wasn't able to solve my issue.

When I test my POST method for the API, it gives me proper response on lambda test and API gateway method test, but when I try it from my react app, it doesn't return the same output.

My lambda snippet:

```
const response = {
        statusCode: 200,
        body: JSON.stringify({payload: {"key": "value"}})
    };

    return response;
```

But the response I am getting using fetch API on my react app:

[image]

I am new to AWS and would appreciate if someone point me in the right direction.

Comment: it looks like there is something in the body there in that image. expand it to see whats inside.

Comment: @Dude I updated the image.

Comment: this platform is so immensely hard to use I immediately went to GCP not AWS

Answer (score 2):

So the fetch API allows you to receive responses as a readablestream, which is what it shows you are receiving in that image there. This resource [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Streams_API/Using_readable_streams), should be helpful in how to properly handle the response.

There are also many other commonly used libraries like axios that are primarily promise / callback driven and you won't have to worry about streams too much unless you want to. You should be able to get fetch working with promises too, but I've never done it myself.

In general, streams are really useful when you have a large amount of data and receiving it all at once in a giant chunk would be really slow, cause timeouts, etc.